# Page object model with PageFactory Impedance

Tags: selenium, pageobjects

I am following the POM guidance found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/SeleniumHQ/selenium/PageObjects.md)

The issue is when a valid user/password is entered, the POM is returning new HomePage(driver) and the new HomePage constructor is validating via the driver being passed, that we are actually on the "home" page.  Naturally, the driver was opened to the login page so finding elements on the home page is futile.  How should the POM method be returning a "PageFactory" home page object actually "opened" to the home page?

Comment: This seems like a timing problem.  PageFactory is instantiating the POM and the WebElements have not been populated yet.  How to deal with "post construct" logic?

Answer (score 0):

The following code in my constructor did the trick!

```
public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
```